# SQLite Connection leaked although everything closed

Tags: android, android-sqlite, sqliteopenhelper

I found many stuff like `close the connection` and `close the cursor`, but I do all this stuff. Still the SQLite connection leaks and I get a warning like this:

```
A SQLiteConnection object for database was leaked!
```

I have a database manager this, which I call in my activities with the following code:

```
DatabaseManager dbm = new DatabaseManager(this);
```

The code of my database manager class follows now:

```
public class DatabaseManager {

    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 9;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "MyApp";
    private Context context = null;
    private DatabaseHelper dbHelper = null;
    private SQLiteDatabase db = null;


    public static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

         public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
             super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
         }

         @Override
         public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

                   //create database tables
         }

         @Override
         public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
                      //destroy and recreate them
         }

     }

     public DatabaseManager(Context ctx) {
         this.context = ctx;
     }

    private DatabaseManager open() throws SQLException {
        dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
        db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

        if (!db.isReadOnly()) {
            db.execSQL("PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;");
        }

        return this;
    }

    private void close() {
        dbHelper.close();
    }
}
```

When I call a database method, I do the following thing:

```
public Object getData() {

    open();

            //... database operations take place ...

    close();

    return data;
}
```

But as I said, I still get this SQLite connection leaked warning.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think You are only closing Your DBHelper, but not the Database itself

Comment: I think you should call db.close() too

Comment: Doesn't matter, if I do this or not. I will get the message anyways. But I read somewhere, that you don't need to do this, when you call the dbHelper.close()

Comment: And why is the `DatabaseHelper` static? This might cause the leak because the `DatabaseHelper` still holds a connection to the db while there is no reference to the `DatabasHelper` left.

Comment: I removed the static, but unfortunately it still leaks

Comment: Is the `close();` line always executed after a successful `open();` line execution? Do you log the exceptions or just swallow them?

Comment: yes, it's always executed

Comment: You should close resources in finaly block for example put this db.close() in finally block

Answer (score 147, accepted):

The bolded font in the citation corresponds to this part in your code:

```
private DatabaseManager open() throws SQLException {
    dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
    db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
```

from: http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2012/05/correctly-managing-your-sqlite-database.html

> Approach #1: Use an Abstract Factory to Instantiate the
>   SQLiteOpenHelper
>
> Declare your database helper as a static instance variable and use the
>   Abstract Factory pattern to guarantee the singleton property. The
>   sample code below should give you a good idea on how to go about
>   designing the DatabaseHelper class correctly.
>
> The static factory getInstance method ensures that only one
>   DatabaseHelper will ever exist at any given time. If the mInstance
>   object has not been initialized, one will be created. If one has
>   already been created then it will simply be returned. 
>   **You should
>   not initialize your helper object using with *`new DatabaseHelper(context)`*. 
>
>   Instead, always use
>   *`DatabaseHelper.getInstance(context)`*, as it guarantees that only one
>   database helper will exist across the entire application's lifecycle.**

```
public static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper { 

  private static DatabaseHelper mInstance = null;

  private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "database_name";
  private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "table_name";
  private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

  public static DatabaseHelper getInstance(Context ctx) {

    // Use the application context, which will ensure that you 
    // don't accidentally leak an Activity's context.
    // See this article for more information: http://bit.ly/6LRzfx
    if (mInstance == null) {
      mInstance = new DatabaseHelper(ctx.getApplicationContext());
    }
    return mInstance;
  }

  /**
   * Constructor should be private to prevent direct instantiation.
   * make call to static factory method "getInstance()" instead.
   */
  private DatabaseHelper(Context ctx) {
    super(ctx, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
  }
}
```

Comment: Great answer. I ran into this problem while working with multiple IntentServices, all working simultaneously out of two different databases. I used this answer except with two separate Factory methods. Cleared up all the memory leak errors. It did add a half second or two to execution time, probably because I no longer have multiple database instances open at once.

Comment: I think the last edit to this answer made by @tdmsoares is erroneous, since `DatabaseHelper` was a static nested class, which can be instantiated. Or did I miss something to notice?

Comment: I get this warning in Android Studio: "Do not place Android context classes in static fields; this is a memory leak (and also breaks Instant Run)".

Comment: If Android Studio complains "Do not place Android context classes in static fields ..." Ignore it as long as we are using the `applicationContext()` we should be okay. [See this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40235834/681159)

Answer (score 3):

The complete example of the above-accepted answer:
It may help someone.

Helper Class:

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "sample.db";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

private static DatabaseHelper mInstance;

private DatabaseHelper(@Nullable Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

public static synchronized DatabaseHelper getInstance(Context context) {

    if (mInstance == null) {
        mInstance = new DatabaseHelper(context.getApplicationContext());
    }
    return mInstance;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    // create table stuff


}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int i, int i1) {

 // drop table stuff

    onCreate(db);
 }
}
```

Activity:

```
SQLiteDatabase database = DatabaseHelper.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).getWritableDatabase();

Cursor cursor = database.query("query");

if (cursor != null) {
   while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
    // stuff
     }
   cursor.close();
   database.close();
 }
```

Comment: Could you please help to solve this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62646206/unable-to-prevent-sqliteconnection-object-leakage)

Answer (score 1):

```
private void method() {
        Cursor cursor = query();
        if (flag == false) {  // WRONG: return before close()
            return;
        }
        cursor.close();
   }
```

Good practice should be like this:

```
    private void method() {
        Cursor cursor = null;
        try {
            cursor = query();
        } finally {
            if (cursor != null)
                cursor.close();  // RIGHT: ensure resource is always recovered
        }
    }
```