# A SQLiteConnection object for database Please fix

Tags: android, sqlite

```
04-11 05:05:17.837: W/SQLiteConnectionPool(6454): A SQLiteConnection object for database Please fix your application to end transactions in progress properly and to close the database when it is no longer needed.
```

this is an error return by my logcat ive searched for the possible solution for this error in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12801602/android-sqlite-leaked) and[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21496221/sqlite-connection-object-leaked-android) saying you should close database but i have this code

```
@Override
     protected void onPause() {
      super.onPause();

      if (db.isOpen()) {
          db.close();
      }
     }
```

on all my ativity so im wondering why i get this error

Comment: are you sure Each Cursor is closed when you're finished with it?

Comment: http://www.devlog.en.alt-area.org/?p=1019

Comment: is there a possibility that a cursor is open even with the code i put above?do i need to put db.close()everytime i open the db for rawquery,insert and update?

Comment: no need of this, you can try the same in onDestroy  also

Comment: http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2012/05/correctly-managing-your-sqlite-database.html

Comment: what do you mean i dont need?the code above i put is not neede?i just use your code?

Comment: sorry i mean no need to call db.close()everytime

Comment: im wondering why my code is not working i still get the error even if i have that close database on all my java file..am i missing something vital?

Comment: ho no, can you able to debug the app and find where it is going to error?

Comment: yes found it it is happening in one of my activities..i tried running all activity and i only get that error when i run that specific activity..but i dont know excatly where in the activity im still looking for it as of now

Comment: is there any thread inside that ?

Comment: what do you mean thread?

Comment: android thread or AsyncTask

Comment: no no no...i dont even have any of that anywhere in my entire project.i dont know how to make that kind of code so i didnt put it in..what i have is simple rawquery update and insert

Comment: and one thing -   protected void onDestroy() {
      super.onDestroy();

      if (db.isOpen()) {
          db.close();
      }
     } try this too

Comment: ok will try this one and be back on you

Comment: the error is so persistent lol...do you think i should remove onPause and just onDestroy i used them both but nothing happened

Comment: hmm... nothing make change on that. you can try and post that code if you can

Comment: where you are oping your db in that i cant find

Comment: your error is on the second on you are giving try by close there and reopen here

Comment: what?i dont understand what you mean

Comment: close the db in the second link it self and reopen in this if you want \

Comment: i have close db on all my activity that is why im wondering why it wont close on this one activity

Comment: OMG yes you want to close all your activty,please google to  know more about that

Comment: no what im saying is i have that code in all of my activity that is wy im wondering why this specific activity is not closing and the rest are doing ok

Comment: are you sure you debug the app and find the place where the error is happen ?

Comment: im debugging now mate..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper { 

  private static DatabaseHelper sInstance;

  private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "database_name";
  private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "table_name";
  private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

  public static DatabaseHelper getInstance(Context context) {

    // Use the application context, which will ensure that you 
    // don't accidentally leak an Activity's context.
    // See this article for more information: http://bit.ly/6LRzfx
    if (sInstance == null) {
      sInstance = new DatabaseHelper(context.getApplicationContext());
    }
    return sInstance;
  }

  /**
   * Constructor should be private to prevent direct instantiation.
   * make call to static factory method "getInstance()" instead.
   */
  private DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
  }
}
```

im currently doing the same thing im doing this tutorial if you want to try it you can you can find it [here](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2012/05/correctly-managing-your-sqlite-database.html)

Comment: Could you please help to solve this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62646206/unable-to-prevent-sqliteconnection-object-leakage)