# A SQLiteConnection object for database was leaked! Please fix your application

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

My application give me this warning

> A SQLiteConnection object for database
>   '+data+data+com_example_test+database' was leaked! Please fix
>   your application to end transactions in progress properly and to close
>   the database when it is no longer needed.

But I close the db object and the cursor after every use.

```
        try {
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
              ...
            }
        } finally {
            if (cursor != null && !cursor.isClosed())
                cursor.close();
        }

...
    db.close();
```

Can you help me for understand what is the problem?
thanks!!!

**UPDATE!**
I try this solution from this post
[SQLite Connection leaked although everything closed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18147354/sqlite-connection-leaked-although-everything-closed/18148718#18148718)

and I don't have memory leak anymore, is it a good solution?

Comment: There is some place where this does not happen.

Comment: it seems problem is in writing to DB, do you have uncommitted transactions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQLite Connection leaked although everything closed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18147354/sqlite-connection-leaked-although-everything-closed)

Answer (score 32):

**Possible Solutions**:

- You have `not committed the transactions` you have started (You should
  always close the transaction once you started)
- Check whether you have closed the cursors you have opened if you are
  using `Sqlite` (Looks like you have done this step from the code you posted)
- Also move the `db.close` to `finally` block
- You have not called `db.close` on a database before deleting it with `context.deleteDatabase(...)` and then recreating it with `dbHelper.getWritableDatabase()`

Answer (score 9):

Just drag that `db.close` up into the `finally` block.

Answer (score 7):

```
//Inside your SQLite helper class
@Override
public synchronized void close () {
    if (db != null) {
        db.close();
        super.close();
    }
}

//Inside the activity that makes a connection to the helper class
@Override
protected void onDestroy () {
    super.onDestroy();
    //call close() of the helper class
    dbHelper.close();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to leave an answer. Unfortunately, it is missing a description and explanation of what you have provided. Please update your question to include this

Answer (score 1):

this code stops the leak and fixes cursor problems.

```
 public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper { 
    
      private static DatabaseHelper sInstance;
    
      private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "database_name";
      private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "table_name";
      private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    
      public static DatabaseHelper getInstance(Context context) {
    
        // Use the application context, which will ensure that you 
        // don't accidentally leak an Activity's context.
        if (sInstance == null) {
          sInstance = new DatabaseHelper(context.getApplicationContext());
        }
        return sInstance;
      }
    
      /**
       * Constructor should be private to prevent direct instantiation.
       * make call to static factory method "getInstance()" instead.
       */
      private DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case the error was caused when y try to download new data and database should be updated.

I solved it instantiating the database by calling a `SELECT 0`. That cause database to be updated, so after that I try to download the new data. And worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you forgot to remove the **break point** of debugging 
sample:

[image: Sample Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was calling to getWritableDatabase or getReadableDatabase and not use it at all. for example  if you use it with "execSQL" execSQL will call "releaseReference"  "Releases a reference to the object, closing the object if the last reference was released."