# "A SQLiteConnection was leaked" warning

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have this problem with sqlite, i'm getting this warning:

```
   A SQLiteConnection object for database '//data//data//com.compapps.booster//databases//booster.db' was leaked!  Please fix your application to end transactions in progress properly and to close the database when it is no longer needed.
```

And logcat is showing that continuously, even after closing the app:

```
Database already exists
```

So i think the programm perform execution even if the app is closed, here is the code of my class:

```
package com.compapps.booster.db;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

import com.compapps.booster.model.AppInfo;
import com.compapps.booster.model.UsedAppInfo;
import com.compapps.booster.utill.Const;

public class ExternalDbOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    // Path to the device folder with databases
    public static String DB_PATH;

    // Database file name
    public static String DB_NAME;
    public SQLiteDatabase database;
    public final Context context;

    public SQLiteDatabase getDb() {
        return database;
    }

    public ExternalDbOpenHelper(Context context, String databaseName,
            int databaseVersion) {
        super(context, databaseName, null, databaseVersion);
        this.context = context;
        // Write a full path to the databases of your application
        String packageName = context.getPackageName();
        DB_PATH = String.format("//data//data//%s//databases//", packageName);
        DB_NAME = databaseName;
        openDataBase();
    }

    // This piece of code will create a database if itï؟½s not yet created
    public void createDataBase() {
        boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();
        if (!dbExist) {

            this.getReadableDatabase();
            try {
                copyDataBase();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(this.getClass().toString(), "Copying error");
                throw new Error("Error copying database!");
            }
        } else {
            Log.i(this.getClass().toString(), "Database already exists");
        }
    }

    // Performing a database existence check
    private boolean checkDataBase() {
        SQLiteDatabase checkDb = null;
        try {
            String path = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
            checkDb = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(path, null,
                    SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            Log.e(this.getClass().toString(), "Error while checking db");
        }
        // Android doesnt like resource leaks, everything should
        // be closed
        if (checkDb != null) {
            checkDb.close();
        }
        return checkDb != null;
    }

    // Method for copying the database
    private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {
        // Open a stream for reading from our ready-made database
        // The stream source is located in the assets
        InputStream externalDbStream = context.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

        // Path to the created empty database on your Android device
        String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

        // Now create a stream for writing the database byte by byte
        OutputStream localDbStream = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

        // Copying the database
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int bytesRead;
        while ((bytesRead = externalDbStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            localDbStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }
        // Dont forget to close the streams
        localDbStream.close();
        externalDbStream.close();
    }

    public SQLiteDatabase openDataBase() throws SQLException {
        String path = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        if (database == null) {
            createDataBase();
        }
        database = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(path, null,
                SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
        return database;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    }

    public void insertAutoKillApps(final ArrayList<AppInfo> listAutoKillApps) {
        for (int i = 0; i < listAutoKillApps.size(); i++) {
            if (listAutoKillApps.get(i).isChecked()) {
                AppInfo info = listAutoKillApps.get(i);
                ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                values.put(Const.TblAutoKillColumn.APP_NAME, info.getAppName());
                values.put(Const.TblAutoKillColumn.PACKAGE_NAME,
                        info.getPkgName());
                values.put(Const.TblAutoKillColumn.PROCESS_ID,
                        info.getProcessId());
                int id = (int) database.insert(Const.TABLE_AUTO_KILL, null,
                        values);

            }
        }
    }

    public int insertAutoKillApp(AppInfo info) {

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(Const.TblAutoKillColumn.APP_NAME, info.getAppName());
        values.put(Const.TblAutoKillColumn.PACKAGE_NAME, info.getPkgName());
        // values.put(Const.TblAutoKillColumn.PROCESS_ID, info.getProcessId());
        int id = (int) database.insert(Const.TABLE_AUTO_KILL, null, values);
        return id;

    }

    public int insertAllAutoKillApp(ArrayList<AppInfo> list) {
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            AppInfo info = list.get(i);
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(Const.TblAutoKillColumn.APP_NAME, info.getAppName());
            values.put(Const.TblAutoKillColumn.PACKAGE_NAME, info.getPkgName());
            // values.put(Const.TblAutoKillColumn.PROCESS_ID,
            // info.getProcessId());
            int id = (int) database.insert(Const.TABLE_AUTO_KILL, null, values);
            if (id != -1) {
                count += 1;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Total app kill inserted " + count);
        return count;

    }

    public boolean deleteAutoKillApp(AppInfo info) {

        int row = database.delete(Const.TABLE_AUTO_KILL,
                Const.TblAutoKillColumn.PACKAGE_NAME + " = ?",
                new String[] { info.getPkgName() });

        if (row != 0) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;

    }

    public int deleteAllAutoKillApp(ArrayList<AppInfo> list) {

        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            AppInfo info = list.get(i);
            int row = database.delete(Const.TABLE_AUTO_KILL,
                    Const.TblAutoKillColumn.PACKAGE_NAME + " = ?",
                    new String[] { info.getPkgName() });
            if (row != 0) {
                count += 1;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Total app kill deleted " + count);
        return count;
    }

    public ArrayList<AppInfo> getAutoKillApps() {
        ArrayList<AppInfo> appList = new ArrayList<AppInfo>();
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + Const.TABLE_AUTO_KILL;
        Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        try {
            if (cursor != null && cursor.getCount() > 0) {
                if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                    do {

                        AppInfo info = new AppInfo();
                        info.setAppName(cursor.getString(0));
                        info.setPkgName(cursor.getString(1));
                        // info.setProcessId(cursor.getInt(2));
                        appList.add(info);
                    } while (cursor.moveToNext());
                }
            }

            return appList;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("Error in getting app auto kill from DB", e.getMessage());
            return appList;
        }
        finally{
            cursor.close();
        }
    }

    public int insertUsedAppInfo(UsedAppInfo uAppInfo, boolean isUpdate) {
        int id = 0;
        if (isUpdate) {
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(Const.TblAppUsedColumn.OPEN_COUNTER,
                    uAppInfo.getCounter());
            values.put(Const.TblAppUsedColumn.OPEN_TIME, uAppInfo.getTime());
            String[] args = new String[] { uAppInfo.getPackage_name() };
            id = (int) database.update(Const.TABLE_APP_USED_DETAIL, values,
                    Const.TblAppUsedColumn.PACKAGE_NAME + "=?", args);
        } else {
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(Const.TblAppUsedColumn.PACKAGE_NAME,
                    uAppInfo.getPackage_name());
            values.put(Const.TblAppUsedColumn.OPEN_COUNTER,
                    uAppInfo.getCounter());
            values.put(Const.TblAppUsedColumn.OPEN_TIME, uAppInfo.getTime());
            id = (int) database.insert(Const.TABLE_APP_USED_DETAIL, null,
                    values);
        }
        return id;
    }

    public UsedAppInfo gettUsedAppInfo(String packageName) {
        UsedAppInfo uAppInfo = null;
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + Const.TABLE_APP_USED_DETAIL
                + " WHERE " + Const.TblAppUsedColumn.PACKAGE_NAME + " = "
                + "\"" + packageName + "\"";

        System.out.println("Query coding: " + selectQuery);
        try {

            Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
            if (cursor != null && cursor.getCount() > 0) {
                if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                    uAppInfo = new UsedAppInfo();
                    uAppInfo.setPackage_name(cursor.getString(0));
                    uAppInfo.setCounter(cursor.getInt(1));
                    uAppInfo.setTime(cursor.getString(2));
                }
                cursor.close();
            }

            return uAppInfo;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("Error in getting app info from db", e.getMessage());
            return null;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void close() {
        if (database != null) {
            database.close();
        }
        super.close();
    }
}
```

Can I have help please, thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQLite Connection leaked although everything closed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18147354/sqlite-connection-leaked-although-everything-closed)

Comment: Close it after you no longer need it.