# Android - Google's Contradiction on Singleton Pattern

Tags: java, android, design-patterns, singleton

I've been reading a bit about Singleton pattern usage in Android and its disadvantages regarding to keeping the Context. In fact, when I implement the following code:

```
private static HttpManager sSingleton;
private Context mContext;

private HttpManager(Context context) {

    mContext = context;
}

public static synchronized HttpManager getInstance(Context context) {

    if (sSingleton == null) {
        sSingleton = new HttpManager(context);
    }

    return sSingleton;
}
```

Android Studio shows me the following warning:

> Do not place Android context classes in static fields (static reference to HttpManager which has field mContext pointing to Context); this is a memory leak and also breaks Instant Run.

However, I can see Singletons implemented and recommended [in this page of Android's docs](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/requestqueue.html#singleton).

> If your application makes constant use of the network, it's probably most efficient to set up a single instance of RequestQueue that will last the lifetime of your app. You can achieve this in various ways. The recommended approach is to implement a singleton class that encapsulates RequestQueue and other Volley functionality.

Since Google is contradicting itself, can someone guide me and advise me on this point?

Comment: Where's the contradiction?

Comment: There is no contradiction. The first part says you shouldn't put *Android context classes* into singletons. Second part says nothing about putting *those* into singletons. It is important to read the text properly and understand what it says.

Comment: `...that will last the lifetime of your app.` probably refers that the object (singleton) will be alive (reference held) as long as the context object is alive, this implies that application context `application.getApplicationContext()` should be used.

Comment: @Luis - If you copy code from Google's docs and paste it into Google's IDE and you get a warning, that's a contradiction.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

> Since Google is contradicting itself

No, it is not.

The quoted Lint warning is not complaining about creating singletons. It is complaining about creating singletons holding a reference to an arbitrary `Context`, as that could be something like an `Activity`. Hopefully, by changing `mContext = context` to `mContext = context.getApplicationContext()`, you will get rid of that warning (though it is possible that this still breaks Instant Run — I cannot really comment on that).

Creating singletons is fine, so long as you do so very carefully, to avoid memory leaks (e.g., holding an indefinite `static` reference to an `Activity`).

Comment: It's weird, because if I create a class with exactly the code you can find in that section (see MySingleton class in [the link I mentioned before](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/requestqueue.html#singleton)), Android Studio shows me that warning. So I inferred that Google is contradicting itself when it suggests you to design a class the way they advise not to do... 
I applied the change you suggest and the warning is still showing; anyway,  thank you for your answer :).

Comment: @NadiaCastelli: The Lint check needs refinement. See [this issue](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=223557).

Comment: Great! The incoherence between their documentation and that warning confused me. Thank you very much!

Comment: So if we ignore the warning and supply `this.getApplicationContext` as context so no memory leak will actually occur, right?

Comment: @Ozuf: Correct. The `Application` context is a pre-existing singleton. It is pre-leaked, in effect. You cannot somehow leak it further. :-)

Comment: Thanks man. I actually thought Google was contraditing itself.

Comment: The lint warning in Android Studio is still there after making your change, this would be due to it not changing the fact of the class still owning a static reference to a context instance.  I'm going to simply ignore the warning for now.

Comment: @CommonsWare, I have the same lint warning, but with a ImageButton. I really need it to access a bunch of buttons, one at a time. ImageButton is set to null after usage. Please provide some advice, if you can.

Comment: @Inoy: "I really need it to access a bunch of buttons, one at a time" -- I really doubt it. Feel free to post a separate question, with a [mcve], and asking for advice for how to avoid putting an `ImageButton` in a `static` field.

Comment: @CommonsWare **thanks for fast reply**, and here you go - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44169270/do-not-place-android-context-classes-in-static-fields-this-is-a-memory-leak

Comment: "No, it is not." YES IT IS. A warning implies you're doing something wrong. If you copy and paste code from Google's docs into Google's IDE and it gives you a warning, that's a contradiction.

Answer (score -2):

This is indeed a contradiction, since in many singletons you will need a context. Have a look at this post, I am using now this approach to avoid the warning in android studio:

[Android Singleton with Global Context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14057273/android-singleton-with-global-context)