# Warning - Memory Leak - Context classes in static fields

Tags: java, android, memory-leaks

I am trying to implement Architecture Components from Codelabs. But I'm getting the below error

> Do not place Android context classes in static fields (static
>   reference to FarmerNetworkDataSource which has field mContext pointing
>   to Context); this is a memory leak (and also breaks Instant Run)
>   less...

I used the code snippet directly from Google Codelabs. You can [refer it here](https://github.com/googlecodelabs/android-build-an-app-architecture-components/blob/arch-training-steps/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/sunshine/data/network/WeatherNetworkDataSource.java)

I have seen some [duplicate questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37709918/warning-do-not-place-android-context-classes-in-static-fields-this-is-a-memory). But i can't figure out which is the best pratice to follow.

Please help & Guide me...

**CODE**

```
public class FarmerNetworkDataSource {

    // For Singleton instantiation
    private static final Object LOCK = new Object();
    private static FarmerNetworkDataSource sInstance;
    private final Context mContext;

    private final AppExecutors mExecutors;

    private FarmerNetworkDataSource(Context context, AppExecutors executors) {
        mContext = context;
        mExecutors = executors;
    }

    /**
     * Get the singleton for this class
     */
    public static FarmerNetworkDataSource getInstance(Context context, AppExecutors executors) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Getting the network data source");
        if (sInstance == null) {
            synchronized (LOCK) {
                sInstance = new FarmerNetworkDataSource(context.getApplicationContext(), executors);
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Made new network data source");
            }
        }
        return sInstance;
    }
}
```

**REPOSITORY**

```
public static FarmerRepository provideRepository(Context context) {
        AppExecutors executors = AppExecutors.getInstance();
        FarmerNetworkDataSource networkDataSource =
                FarmerNetworkDataSource.getInstance(context.getApplicationContext(), executors);
        return FarmerRepository.getInstance(networkDataSource, executors);
    }
```

Comment: Looking at the source from the github repository you have    `WeatherNetworkDataSource networkDataSource =
                WeatherNetworkDataSource.getInstance(context.getApplicationContext(), executors);` What context are you passing to the constructor of `FarmerNetworkDataSource` activity context should not live longer than activity lifecycle

Comment: @Raghunandan I have added the code where the DataSource is created

Comment: i downloaded the repo and running lint on the same. If you are using application context nothing to worry and also what context is used in provideRepository

Comment: its a lint warning that you see. There is no leak in the repository code you linked to. You can use leak canary https://github.com/square/leakcanary  and look for memory leaks in your code

Comment: That's not an error, it's a warning! We are programmers, we ignore warnings!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Warning: Do not place Android context classes in static fields; this is a memory leak (and also breaks Instant Run)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37709918/warning-do-not-place-android-context-classes-in-static-fields-this-is-a-memory)

Answer (score 3):

My way around it is:

```
private static WeakReference<Context> appContext;

public static Context getAppContext() {
    if (appContext == null)
        return null;
    return appContext.get();
}
```

> **WeakReference** influences the garbage collector. Most objects that are
>   referenced must be kept in memory until they are unreachable. But with
>   WeakReference, objects that are referenced can be collected.

I used it in a couple of projects and it proved to be very handy.