# How to get access to view elements from adapter kotlin?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I'm moving from java to kotlin and I faced with some difficulties which are connected with static method usage at kotlin. I'd like to get access from recyclerView adapter to views at my activity. At Java I did smth like that at adapter:

```
WriteResponseMess.deleteAttachment(position);
```

and static method at my activity:

```
public static void deleteAttachment(int adapterPosition) {
        mNames = adapter.getItems();
        mNames.remove(adapterPosition);
        adapter.updateNames(mNames);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        mNames = adapter.getItems();
    }
```

right now I want to do it via kotlin. The main tack is that I have to delete item of RV and update views. I have read [this](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/object-declarations.html#object-declarations) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51819983/kotlin-update-view-using-function-created-in-companion-object) resources and I have done smth like that:

```
companion object {
        @JvmStatic
        fun deleteAttachment(position: Int) {

        }
    }
```

but I don't have any access to activity variables, so what I have to do in that situation?

Comment: Try `WriteResponseMess.Companion.deleteAttachment(position);`. is this what you are asking ?

Comment: With annotation @JvmStatic it should work without Companion

Comment: @ADM, I have the access to this method, but variables are still closed for me :(

Comment: You're holding data within static fields. This means that you have serious correctness and architectural problems. Fix them first (`static` is only for constants), migrate them (if this makes sense).

Comment: @Miha_x64, I'm moving from java and don't know some parts of kotlin, I suggested that it will be right for this task, so I don't have to use static as I understand? how I can solve this task without static fields? via interface or like what?

Comment: @AndrewGoroshko I can't answer without knowing why do you use statics. If you need to pass data across activities, consider implementing `Parcelable` and using Intent Extras.

Comment: @AndrewGoroshko, why is that method static?

Comment: @r2rek, because I need to use method from adapter

Comment: @AndrewGoroshko and are you using it from outside the activity?

Comment: @r2rek, about what are you asking?? about method or what? I use this method inside activity, but I don't have access to activity members

Comment: If you're using it inside the activity that has the adapter, then you shouldn't make it static

Comment: but I need to send data from adapter to activity, and as I understand I have to use static for it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `static block` can access only **`static members`**.

The activity `member variables` should also be a part of the `companion object`.

For instance :-

```
companion object {
    var mNames : MutableList<Name> = mutableListOf // is a member variable
    ......
    fun deleteAttachment(position: Int) {

    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand about member variables, right now I "see" this fun, but I can't get access to activity variables anyway

Comment: You have to **make your activity variables static** to gain access to them by a **static function** ..  @AndrewGoroshko `deleteAttachment` is a static function.

Comment: hmmm... this companion object is placed at my activity, and I thought that I can get access to activity variables like in Java

Comment: and how I have to change `var` to `static`? in kotlin as I understand we have smth like companion, but I didn't manage to use it for my purposes

Comment: `To achieve what you want` ... you need to use an `interface or lambda functions` in kotlin ... **which is altogether a separate question** . Check this https://antonioleiva.com/lambdas-kotlin/ @AndrewGoroshko

Comment: so as I understood I can't do it like in Java?)

Comment: Correct.. in this case.. you cant. but you can surely use `lambdas` which is also recommended in java... instead of using static functions.. @AndrewGoroshko

Comment: thank you for your help, I didn't understand bigger part of info which you gave, so I will go into kotlin and will try to solve this problem :)

Comment: To clarify: this answer suggests converting existing bugs to a new language.

Comment: @Miha_x64, which bugs did you mean?

Comment: @AndrewGoroshko, I mean keeping data in static fields. This is implies coupling, memory leak, and they will disappear after process restart.

Comment: @Miha_x64, I know that static fields cause some problems, but I managed to solve this task only via static fields :(