# How do I call the GDPR consent form inside static method

Tags: java, android

Inside the onConsentFormLoaded method it says for “variable ‘form’ is accessed from within inner class must be declared final” but then when I declare it final it then shows a error “variable ‘form’ might not have been initialized” I tried declaring 'private static ConsentForm form" at the top of my class but then it gives a error saying about placing android context classes inside a static field will result in a memory leak so im not sure where to go from here ?

```
  public static void settings()
    {
    final AppActivity activity = ((AppActivity) Cocos2dxHelper.getActivity());

    activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {

    URL privacyUrl = null;
    try {
    // TODO: Replace with your app’s privacy policy URL.
    privacyUrl = new URL(“https://privacy-policy”);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    }

    ConsentForm form = new ConsentForm.Builder(getContext(), privacyUrl).withListener(new ConsentFormListener() {

    @Override
    public void onConsentFormLoaded() {
    // Consent form loaded successfully.
    Log.i(“consent”, “consent loaded”);
    form.show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConsentFormOpened() {
    // Consent form was displayed.
    }

    @Override
    public void onConsentFormClosed(ConsentStatus consentStatus, Boolean userPrefersAdFree) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConsentFormError(String errorDescription) {
    // Consent form error.
    Log.i(“consent”, errorDescription);
    }
    })
    .withPersonalizedAdsOption().withNonPersonalizedAdsOption().build();

    form.load();
    }
    });
    }
```

Comment: Not entirely sure about the C++ code, but can you get an instance?

Comment: this is in myactivity, i already got the C++ to Java part now I just need to be able to call form.show inside the onConsentFormLoaded method